# why the Colab pro doesn't work with premium Gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I paid for Colab pro by two days ago and now I can't use the GPU,the problem is:

```
    Want access to premium GPUs?
You are subscribed to Pro but have zero compute units available.
```

how I can solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3132

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/xs62o9/what_exactly_is_a_compute_unit/

Comment: Those are some pointer. Your question is unfit to SO. Voting to close.